# Invisible XML grammar wont work for this entry (using Coffeepot)

Tags: java, xml, grammar, bnf, invisible-xml

I am using coffeepot in a Java runtime to try to convert the following text:

```
WARNING: Do Not Modify This File!
Check 24.1.6 Data File
CONTROL 1 (
  code = CEZ_90_1_2016
  compliance mode = UA
  version = 24.1.6 )
LOCATION 1 (
  state = Texas
  city =  USA )
BUILDING 1 (
  project type = NEW_CONSTRUCTION
  bldg use type = WHOLE_BLDG
  feet bldg height = 0.000
  number of stories = 1
  is nonresidential conditioning = TRUE
  is residential conditioning = FALSE
  is semiheated conditioning = FALSE
  conditioning = HEATING_AND_COOLING)
ENVELOPE 1 (
  use orient details = TRUE
  use vlt details = TRUE
  use cool roof performance details = FALSE )
AG WALL 1 (
  wall type = MASONRY_AG_WALL
  next to uncond space = FALSE
  concrete thickness = 12.00
  concrete density = 115.00
  furring type = NO_FURRING
  cmu type = CMU_PARTIAL_GROUT_CELLS_EMPTY
  list position = 1
  description = <|Concrete Block:12", Partially Grouted, Cells Empty|>
  assembly type = <|Exterior Wall 1|>
  parent number = 0
  bldg use key = 1884629903
  continuous rvalue = 10.00
  daylight credit = 0.000
  orientation = WEST
  allowance type = ENV_ALLOWANCE_NONE
  exemption type = ENV_EXEMPTION_NONE
  valid allowance type = FALSE
  valid exemption type = FALSE
  construction type = NON_RESIDENTIAL 
  adjacent space type = ADJACENT_SPACE_EXTERIOR 
  gross area = 3377.000)
DOOR 4 (
  door type = INSUL_METAL_DOOR
  door open type = SWINGING_DOOR
  list position = 3
  description = <|Insulated Metal|>
  assembly type = <|Door 1|>
  parent number = 1
  bldg use key = 1884629903
  prop uvalue = 0.100000
  daylight credit = 0.000
  orientation = WEST
  allowance type = ENV_ALLOWANCE_NONE
  exemption type = ENV_EXEMPTION_NONE
  valid allowance type = FALSE
  valid exemption type = FALSE
  construction type = NON_RESIDENTIAL 
  adjacent space type = ADJACENT_SPACE_EXTERIOR 
  gross area = 21.000)
AG WALL 2 (
  wall type = METAL_FRAME_16_AG_WALL
  next to uncond space = FALSE
  list position = 4
  description = <|Steel-Framed, 16" o.c.|>
  assembly type = <|Exterior Wall 2|>
  parent number = 0
  bldg use key = 1884629903
  cavity rvalue = 21.00
  continuous rvalue = 0.00
  daylight credit = 0.000
  orientation = NORTH
  allowance type = ENV_ALLOWANCE_NONE
  exemption type = ENV_EXEMPTION_NONE
  valid allowance type = FALSE
  valid exemption type = FALSE
  construction type = NON_RESIDENTIAL 
  adjacent space type = ADJACENT_SPACE_EXTERIOR 
  gross area = 42.000)
```

to:

```
<Document xmlns:ixml="http://invisiblexml.org/NS" ixml:state="ambiguous">
   <data>
      <name>CONTROL</name>
      <number>1</number>
      <property>
         <name>code</name>
         <value>CEZ_90_1_2016</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>compliance mode</name>
         <value>UA</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>version</name>
         <value>24.1.6</value>
      </property>
   </data>
   <data>
      <name>LOCATION</name>
      <number>1</number>
      <property>
         <name>state</name>
         <value>Texas</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>city</name>
         <value> USA</value>
      </property>
   </data>
   <data>
      <name>BUILDING</name>
      <number>1</number>
      <property>
         <name>project type</name>
         <value>NEW_CONSTRUCTION</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>bldg use type</name>
         <value>WHOLE_BLDG</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>feet bldg height</name>
         <value>0.000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>number of stories</name>
         <value>1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>is nonresidential conditioning</name>
         <value>TRUE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>is residential conditioning</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>is semiheated conditioning</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>conditioning</name>
         <value>HEATING_AND_COOLING</value>
      </property>
   </data>
   <data>
      <name>ENVELOPE</name>
      <number>1</number>
      <property>
         <name>use orient details</name>
         <value>TRUE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>use vlt details</name>
         <value>TRUE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>use cool roof performance details</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
   </data>
   <data>
      <name>AG WALL</name>
      <number>1</number>
      <property>
         <name>wall type</name>
         <value>MASONRY_AG_WALL</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>next to uncond space</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>concrete thickness</name>
         <value>12.00</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>concrete density</name>
         <value>115.00</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>furring type</name>
         <value>NO_FURRING</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>cmu type</name>
         <value>CMU_PARTIAL_GROUT_CELLS_EMPTY</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>list position</name>
         <value>1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>description</name>
         <value>&lt;|Concrete Block:12", Partially Grouted, Cells Empty|></value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>assembly type</name>
         <value>&lt;|Exterior Wall 1|></value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>parent number</name>
         <value>0</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>bldg use key</name>
         <value>1884629903</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>continuous rvalue</name>
         <value>10.00</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>daylight credit</name>
         <value>0.000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>orientation</name>
         <value>WEST</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>allowance type</name>
         <value>ENV_ALLOWANCE_NONE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>exemption type</name>
         <value>ENV_EXEMPTION_NONE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>valid allowance type</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>valid exemption type</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>construction type</name>
         <value>NON_RESIDENTIAL </value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>adjacent space type</name>
         <value>ADJACENT_SPACE_EXTERIOR </value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>gross area</name>
         <value>3377.000</value>
      </property>
   </data>
   <data>
      <name>DOOR</name>
      <number>4</number>
      <property>
         <name>door type</name>
         <value>INSUL_METAL_DOOR</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>door open type</name>
         <value>SWINGING_DOOR</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>list position</name>
         <value>3</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>description</name>
         <value>&lt;|Insulated Metal|></value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>assembly type</name>
         <value>&lt;|Door 1|></value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>parent number</name>
         <value>1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>bldg use key</name>
         <value>1884629903</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>prop uvalue</name>
         <value>0.100000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>daylight credit</name>
         <value>0.000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>orientation</name>
         <value>WEST</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>allowance type</name>
         <value>ENV_ALLOWANCE_NONE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>exemption type</name>
         <value>ENV_EXEMPTION_NONE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>valid allowance type</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>valid exemption type</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>construction type</name>
         <value>NON_RESIDENTIAL </value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>adjacent space type</name>
         <value>ADJACENT_SPACE_EXTERIOR </value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>gross area</name>
         <value>21.000</value>
      </property>
   </data>
   <data>
      <name>AG WALL</name>
      <number>2</number>
      <property>
         <name>wall type</name>
         <value>METAL_FRAME_16_AG_WALL</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>next to uncond space</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>list position</name>
         <value>4</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>description</name>
         <value>&lt;|Steel-Framed, 16" o.c.|></value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>assembly type</name>
         <value>&lt;|Exterior Wall 2|></value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>parent number</name>
         <value>0</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>bldg use key</name>
         <value>1884629903</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>cavity rvalue</name>
         <value>21.00</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>continuous rvalue</name>
         <value>0.00</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>daylight credit</name>
         <value>0.000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>orientation</name>
         <value>NORTH</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>allowance type</name>
         <value>ENV_ALLOWANCE_NONE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>exemption type</name>
         <value>ENV_EXEMPTION_NONE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>valid allowance type</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>valid exemption type</name>
         <value>FALSE</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>construction type</name>
         <value>NON_RESIDENTIAL </value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>adjacent space type</name>
         <value>ADJACENT_SPACE_EXTERIOR </value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>gross area</name>
         <value>42.000</value>
      </property>
   </data>
</Document>
```

with the following grammar:

```
Document = Warning, check, data+, #a? .
-Warning = -"WARNING: Do Not Modify This File!", -#a.
-check = -"Check 24.1.6 Data File", -#a .
data = name, -' ', number, -' (', -#a, property++-#a, -' '?, -')', -#a .

name = namechar, (namechar | ' ')*, namechar .
-namechar = ['A'-'Z'] | ['a'-'z'] .
number = ['0'-'9']+ .
property = -' '*, name, -' = ', value .
value = ~[#a]+ .
```

I execute coffeepot with the following command line:

```
java -jar coffeepot-1.99.11.jar --input:input.txt --grammar:grammar.txt --pretty-print
```

However, I get the following error:

```
<fail xmlns:ixml="http://invisiblexml.org/NS" ixml:state="failed">
   <line>1</line>
   <column>34</column>
   <pos>33</pos>
   <unexpected>!</unexpected>
   <permitted>#A</permitted>
   <also-predicted>'W'</also-predicted>
</fail>
```

I am very new to this, but once I can get through this hump I can start dissecting, reverse engineering this, and etc... :D thank you!

Comment: It looks to me like there is an off-by-one bug in coffeepot's error reporting. It's not the `!` which it didn't expect; it's the character which follows. I assume that the problem is that the character which follows `!` is not a newline character (which is what the grammar says should be there) but rather a character return; in other words, the first character of the infamous two-byte CRLF line-end sequence, which goes back at least to MS-DOS. These often get in the way if you create a file with Windows text editors and then read them in Unix or a Unix subsystem.

Comment: If that's the problem and you don't want to convert your input to Unix line endings, the usual solution would be to use `-#d?,-#a` instead of `-#a` (or define `NL` to that sequence, in order to reduce clutter in your grammar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the text to Unix using Notepad++ and it worked like a charm.

Fix:
In Notepad++, go to Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF)